# How to create and set a system-wide environmental variable in Ubuntu through makefile?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I'm trying to create a system-wide environmental variable `TEST_ENV_ONE`.
I want to use it right after executing makefile without logout and after rebooting. So I'm trying to repeat manual moves like `export` variable and write it ti `/etc/environment`

I wrote a makefile like this, but it doesn't work:

```
var_value := some_string
TEST_ENV_ONE := $(var_value)

vars:
    $(shell export TEST_ENV_ONE=$(var_value))
    grep  'TEST_ENV_ONE=' /etc/environment || "TEST_ENV_ONE=\"$(var_value)\"" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment > /dev/null
```

Comment: As @MadScientist noted in his answer what you're trying to do is impossible on a POSIX (i.e., UNIX) like operating system. Also, why in the world would you use a makefile for this task? If what you're attempting were even possible it would be far simpler to just do it via a script.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is basically impossible on a POSIX system as you've stated it.  The environment of a process is inherited from its parent (the process that started it) and once a process is running, its environment cannot ever be changed externally.  That includes by its children, or by modifying some other file.

You can, by modifying /etc/environment, change the environment for new logins but this will not change the environment of any existing shell or its child.

That being said, your makefile also has a number of problems:

```
$(shell export TEST_ENV_ONE=$(var_value))
```

This is doubly-not right.  First, it's an anti-pattern to use the make `$(shell ...)` function inside a recipe script.  Recipes are already shell scripts so it's useless (and can lead to unexpected behavior) to use `$(shell ...)` with them.

Second, this is a no-op: what this does is start a shell, tell the shell to set an environment variable and export it, then the shell exits.  When the shell exits, all the changes to its environment are lost (obviously, because it exited!)  So this does nothing.

Next:

```
grep  'TEST_ENV_ONE=' /etc/environment || "TEST_ENV_ONE=\"$(var_value)\"" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment > /dev/null
```

This does nothing because the statement `"TEST_ENV_ONE=\"$(var_value)\""` sets an environment variable but generates no output, so there's no input to the `sudo tee` command and nothing happens.  I expect you forgot an `echo` command here:

```
grep  'TEST_ENV_ONE=' /etc/environment || echo TEST_ENV_ONE=\"$(var_value)\" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment > /dev/null
```

However as I mention above, modifying `/etc/environment` will only take effect for *new logins* to the system, it won't modify any existing login or shell.

Comment: In addition to all your other points I was left wondering why in the heck they are even using a makefile for this task. Something that would be far simpler to do as a simple script or function; assuming env vars worked the way they want them to behave.

Comment: Impossible to say, but one assumes that the value they want to set isn't really `static_string` so much as something specific to a given make invocation.  But as you suggest, there's not nearly enough info here to guess what the actual requirement is.